# How can I build a macro that functions as both spells on one of my talent tree's choice nodes?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As a Shadow Priest, one of the choice nodes available on my talent tree is between Dark Ascension and Void Eruption. It's annoying when I switch this node as I have to routinely re-add the related cooldown ability to my action bar when I switch between them.

Is there a way to have both spells operate via the same macro so I can just use that macro as opposed to continually, and annoyingly, switching the spell that's on my bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the pre-patch, Blizzard [released "known" and "noknown" conditionals](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/wow/t/psa-new-macro-conditional-known/1399019), which can easily be used for choice node spells. The syntax for the conditional is `[known:<spellid>]` or `[known:<spellname>]`. This will also function as expected with `#showtooltip`.

The macro should look something like:

```
#showtooltip
/cast [known:Dark Ascension] Dark Ascension; Void Eruption
```

Since Dark Ascension and Void Eruption are mutually exclusive, there's no break in logic here. If you select the question mark icon as the macro's icon, it will also take the icon of whatever spell you currently have learned.

Notably, as a Shadow Priest, Void Eruption will turn into Void Bolt while you are in Voidform. You do not need to specify a cast of Void Bolt in your macro, as Void Eruption basically turns into Void Bolt while you are in Voidform and while you are in Voidform, pressing this macro's button will cast Void Bolt as ordinarily expected.